# Less accurate fractions when rounding in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, rounding

Hi all I am very new to python and this is my first project. I am creating a calculator that when I enter the perimeter of a circle it will calculate the diameter for me. Such as handlebars on a motorcycle without taking the grips off.

I got it to work but I really need it to be less accurate like maybe round to the nearest 1/8. If I type 2.75 it works perfect but if I type 2.76 its give insane fractions. I would still like it to read 7/8 until its more then half way to 1.0

Here is what I have so far any help you can offer would be great.

```
from fractions import Fraction

print "Do you wish to calculate the Diameter or Radius from a perimeter measurement? Type 'd' or 'r'"
var = raw_input("Please type 'd' or 'r'")


if var == 'd':
    print "Now type the perimeter measurement for the diameter you would like calculate."
    cir = float(raw_input())
    answer = cir/3.1415926535
    rnd = round(answer, 3 )
    frac = Fraction(rnd).limit_denominator()
    print rnd
    print "The diameter of a %s perimeter is" % cir, frac
elif var == 'r':
    print "Now type the perimeter measurement for the Radius you would like to calculate."
    cir = float(raw_input())
    answer = cir/3.1415926535/2
    print "The Radius of a %s perimeter is" % cir, answer 
else:
    print "Error: You did not type 'd' or 'r' Please run again"
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for fractions with a small power-of-2 denominator (as common when measuring inches), or whatever "simple" fraction comes closest to matching?  For example, would you want a value like 0.35 to round to 3/8 (inaccurate, but easy to measure) or 1/3 ("simpler" and more accurate, but not on most rulers)?  Or do you _always_ want a value in eights, even if it could be reduced further --- is 2/8 preferable to 1/4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple if you need same denominator.

```
denominator = 8
rnd = round(answer * denominator)
frac = Fraction(int(rnd), denonimator)
```

Comment: That's a very bad idea; if you try to round Pi to its nearest 1/8, you get 25/8 which is a very poor approximation in comparison to 22/7. See my answer below.

Comment: @Baruchel If the OP is using a yardstick with units of 1/8 inches (yes, really a bad idea, when there are millimeters!) then a result in 1/7 units will be completely useless to him. It may upset your inner mathematician, but a useful result may be more important than numeric accuracy in the 1/100 magnitude.

Comment: @tripleee Why "upset"? I agree with you up to some point; but I am convinced that if we use computers we will also not exactly think the same way as when using a yardstick.

Answer (score 0):

You can round it to nearest 1/8th.

```
In [1]: from fractions import Fraction

In [14]: Fraction(round(2.6*8)/8).limit_denominator()
Out[14]: Fraction(21, 8)

In [4]: Fraction(round(2.75*8)/8).limit_denominator()
Out[4]: Fraction(11, 4)

In [5]: Fraction(round(2.9*8)/8).limit_denominator()
Out[5]: Fraction(23, 8)
```

Comment: That's a very bad idea; if you try to round Pi to its nearest 1/8, you get 25/8 which is a very poor approximation in comparison to 22/7. See my answer below.

Comment: The question says **I got it to work but I really need it 2 be less accurate like maybe round to the nearest 1/8**.

Comment: Please, mathematicians have been spending time for centuries to build theories explaining why approximating Pi with a denominator less than 8 should be 22/7, why not using their tools? By the way, 22/7 **actually** approximates Pi to the nearest 1/8 (and even much better)...

Comment: I agree with you. But the question asked here actually wants to build something like this to round the number to nearest 1/8th.

Comment: The `limit_denominator` calls here are redundant: they don't change the result.

Answer (score 0):

All previous methods use the `round(x*8)/8` method which is wrong; of course, when I am in a hurry, I somethime (not often) use it, but it is a wrong method.

**Method 1 (the most orthodox)**

There are four *best approximations* to 2.76 according to the theory of continued fractions, namely:

```
2, 3, 11/4, 69/25
```

You could argue that 11/4 is the same as 22/8 (as asked) but you can't expect it to work that way for any number. Take Pi, for instance; `round(3.1415926*8)/8` is 25/8 which is a very poor approximation by comparison with 22/7: **22/7 actually approximates Pi to 1/8 but even far better (while being simpler than 25/8)!** The original poster wants an approximation to 1/8. Have a look at the three following fractions: 22/7, 25/8, 314/100; all approximate Pi to 1/8 but which one would you choose (probably the first; now: the first is not only the simplest of the three fractions; it is also the most accurate)? The simplest fraction doing better than 22/7 jumps to less than 1e-4 as its accuracy (namely 333/106)!

Furthermore, if you want to approximate 0.5, you can't be happy with 4/8! Of course the `fractions` module will probably cancel it down at initialization, but that's anyway a very bad sign: your method does not want to produce something like 4/8 even as an intermediate step!

A joke: take 0.33333333... and try the `round(x*8)/8` method; you will discover that 3/8 approximates 0.33333333... to 1/8, which is true of course, but... How to say it politely?

Have a look at the following function; you can safely rely on it for approximating a number:

```
from fractions import Fraction                                              

def rationalize(x, maxden=1000):
    p0, p1 = 0, 1
    q0, q1 = 1, 0
    a = int(x) if x >= 0 else int(x-1)
    while q1 <= maxden:
        p = a*p1 + p0
        q = a*q1 + q0
        p0, p1 = p1, p
        q0, q1 = q1, q
        if x==a:
            if q1 <= maxden: return Fraction(p1, q1)
            else: return Fraction(p0, q0)
        x = 1/(x-a)
        a = int(x)
    return Fraction(p0, q0)
```

If you try it with Pi with `maxden=8` you get 22/7 as expected (and no longer the insane 25/8).

The function returns a *convergent* to your number built from consecutive partial quotients in the continued fraction expansion of the number. See explanations at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

**Method 2**

Some Computer Algebra System also use a linear integer relation algorithm (for instance PSLQ) for this problem; for instance Sympy uses the `mpmath.pslq` method for doing it. It is very convenient and it gives the good result because PSLQ returns the vector giving an integer relation between 1 and x with the smallest norm. But it is still more complicated than the other method.

Comment: Could your mention whether the function (`rationalize()`) always produces the best approximation and in what sense it is the best? Do you have a link that explains the theory?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Right! I edited my post and added the link. Regards.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I think the OP wants the results in multiples of 1/8th (1/8, 1/4, 1/2). 22/7 is the best approximation of Pi, sure - I learnt that school - but that wasn't the question asked.

Comment: @SiHa Hummm... Maybe you are right, but I re-read the question, tried the code and finally stay up with my understanding. If the user types: 1.0472, my answer leads to "the diameter is 1/3" while the other methods lead to "The diameter is 3/8" (exact answer being 0.333334...). To be fair, even the simplest input "1" leads to such a case. Don't forget he/she is writing an interface with an user; user wants to read the simplest fraction (if also the most accurate). Regards.

Comment: @Baruchel: are you aware that the `Fraction` type already has a `limit_denominator` method which produces the best possible approximation for a given denominator bound?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the `rationalize` function in this answer *doesn't* always produce the best approximation, since it ignores the [semiconvergents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiconvergent). For an example (there are many), take `x = 0.6951542`. The `rationalize` function with `max_den=1000` gives a result of `244/351`, but the closest fraction with denominator bounded by `1000` is `545/784` (which is what `Fraction.limit_denominator` produces in this case).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are right about the semiconvergents, there are two definitions of "best approximations" and I was using the most restictive one.